# How to get Sum from relationship in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

//Client Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'client_name', 'plan_id', 'client_type'
    ];

public function plan(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Plan::class, 'plan_id', 'id');
    }
```

// Plan Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'price'
    ];

public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
```

I want to get total price of all clients where client_type = something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
function getClientTypeTotal($clientType)
{
    return Client::where('client_type', $clientType)->get()->sum(function ($client) {
        return $client->plan->price;
    })
}
```

Comment: This won't work with multiple plans that have different prices.

Comment: I am assuming `$plan` is already the instance of the plan he is trying to calculate, and I understand he is asking for the total amount for a plan, not for every plan he has, maybe I understood the question wrong.

Comment: I want to get total price of all clients where client_type = something

Comment: My bad! Then I did not understand what were you trying to achieve, I'm editing my answer.